# Set list view item's dimensions based on screen size

Tags: android, listview, measurement

I'm trying to make a horizontal list view that sizes its list items based on the size of the screen. The list items should take up 80% of the screen width and have a small margin. A small section of the next list item should also be visible on the screen. Like this:

[image]

The design requires an `Adapter` of some kind, I'm using this implementation of a horizontally orientated `ListView`: https://github.com/dinocore1/DevsmartLib-Android/tree/master/devsmartlib .
Is it possible to measure the views supplied to the `Adapter` like this? I've tried using `android:layout_weight` but it hasn't worked for me.

Thanks.

Comment: How did u solve that problem. I also need it.

Comment: @JatinMalwal Have a look at this:  http://commonsware.com/blog/2012/08/20/multiple-view-viewpager-options.html. I used the first one. :)

Comment: Okay Thanks. I used other similar kind lib.